# Sliding door technique with semi transparent backgrounds?

Tags: css

I'm working on a button with a glossy appearance. The button can have various colors and sizes. This is what i have done so far:

```
.btn-zen-inverse, .btn-zen-inverse:hover{
    color: white;
    background: 
    url("../img/btn_right.png") no-repeat right 0,
    url("../img/btn_left.png") no-repeat  left 0,
    url("../img/btn_center.png") repeat-x 42px 0;
  background-color: #273032;
  background-size: contain; 
  line-height: 50px;
  margin: 12px 18px 3px 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 2px solid white !important;
}
```

The images referenced are alpha transparent. The idea is to set the color based on the background-color attribute. The image has a few other properties aswell, but those are merely estetic.

This ofcorse renders an image that looks like this! 
I would like the center-image to be visible only in the central part of the image. As you can see from my css. This only has to work perectly in the latest version of the big 4 browsers.

[image]

This is what I would like it to look like:

[image]

One suggesion is to do this with background-gradients. If that is possible, I need to define the background position similairly to the way padding/margin works. Is that possible?

The design contains:
2 borders: 
  one white
  one gradiented, 
A background gradient.
and a 1px thick vertical gradient at the very top.

Comment: Anyways, as I see the design. This one can be done using CSS3 properties as linear-gradient, box-shadow etc.

Comment: my bad... updated question with deatils on the design...

Comment: Tried hard to understand what you want, but failed. Can you provide what exactly you want to achieve, may be with picture.

Comment: RomanTheGreat: I added an image, the colors are a bit of, but I think you get the picture ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is as closer as i can get with CSS only.

Note that multiple backgrounds are not supported by IE8. Neither is the following code, but at least you don't need images.

[image: button preview]

[**Live demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/eH36t/)

HTML:

```
<a class="button dark" href="#"><span>Prova Zenconomy Gratis</span></a>
```

CSS:

```
.button {
    display:inline-block;
    border:2px solid;
    -webkit-border-radius:5px;
    -moz-border-radius:5px;
    border-radius:5px;
    line-height:40px;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 4px 1px rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.7);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 4px 1px rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.7);
    box-shadow: 0 0 4px 1px rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.7);
}
.button > span {
    padding:0 40px;
    display:block;
    border:3px solid;
    -webkit-border-radius:5px;
    -moz-border-radius:5px;
    border-radius:5px;
}
.button.dark {
    border-color:#FFF;
    color:#FFF;
    background:#030303;
}
.button.dark > span {
    border-color:#000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 3px 5px -1px rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 3px 5px -1px rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
    box-shadow: inset 0 3px 5px -1px rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
    background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,0.3) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(255,255,255,0.3)), color-stop(100%,rgba(255,255,255,0)));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,0.3) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,0.3) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,0.3) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255,255,255,0.3) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);
}
```

There are 2 classes (`.button` for the layout and `.dark` for colors and gradient) so that you can have different types of buttons in your page.

Comment: This is magnificent! I'd love to take a look at the svg, is there some way to open it in a vector-based program?

Comment: Yes @KristofferNolgren , go to the [Microsoft SVG Gradient Background Maker](http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/graphics/svggradientbackgroundmaker/default.html) and click on "Click to paste existing CSS base64-URL background-image markup" :-)

Comment: is says it's parsed successfully but nothing happened

Comment: @KristofferNolgren you've to copy the SVG source output and save it in an SVG file. Then you can open it with an editor (Illustrator or just [Google it](http://www.google.com/search?q=open+svg) )

Comment: I see... I ended up adding two css gradients to the background rather than using svg, wich worked out grate! Like this: background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,.21) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 50%), -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0.3) 50%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%) no-repeat; /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */

Answer (score 0):

Please [check this code](http://jsfiddle.net/xQvfd/) as solution to your query.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<style type="text/css">
    .btn-zen-inverse, .btn-zen-inverse:hover{
    color:#fff;
    background: 
    url("https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-V_jjGSjquMg/UHPqq7_FfvI/AAAAAAAAA6s/fK5QEHGzC9I/s128/left.png") no-repeat right 0,
    url("https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-V_jjGSjquMg/UHPqq7_FfvI/AAAAAAAAA6s/fK5QEHGzC9I/s128/left.png") no-repeat  left 0,
    url("https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-JgxTtVru7R8/UHPqq1RgAII/AAAAAAAAA6o/gmfFayABGfQ/s128/center.png") repeat-x 42px 0;
  background-color: #ff09f9;
  background-size: contain; 
  line-height: 50px;
  margin: 12px 18px 3px 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 2px solid white !important;
  text-align:center
}

</style>

</head>

<body>
<div class="btn-zen-inverse">Content</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This one has the same problem, the center part overlays the left and right part get darker (as the alpha layers compound)